# In PHP is it possible to inspect content of a Zip file without extracting its content first?

Tags: php, zip

I have seen the ZipArchive class in PHP which lets you read zip files. But I'm wondering if there is a way to iterate though its content without extracting the file first

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP library that can list contents of zip / rar files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524186/php-library-that-can-list-contents-of-zip-rar-files)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As found as a comment on http://www.php.net/ziparchive:

> The following code can be used to get a list of all the file names in
>   a zip file.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $za = new ZipArchive(); 
>
> $za->open('theZip.zip'); 
>
> for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
>     $stat = $za->statIndex( $i ); 
>     print_r( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL ); 
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must have missed the numFiles field when looking through ZipArchive documentation.

Comment: The ZipArchive object's interface is just strange.

Comment: @flu: Just my thought right now. Looks even worse than Plain Old PHP without classes.

Comment: $za just contains true in my case ... oO

Comment: One liner for fun: `for($i = 0, ($zip = new ZipArchive())->open('example.zip'); $name = $zip->getNameIndex($i++);) echo $name . PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 18):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-read.php

```
<?php
$zip = zip_open("test.zip");

if (is_resource($zip))
  {
  while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
    {
    echo "<p>";
    echo "Name: " . zip_entry_name($zip_entry) . "<br />";

    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry))
      {
      echo "File Contents:<br/>";
      $contents = zip_entry_read($zip_entry);
      echo "$contents<br />";
      zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
      }
    echo "</p>";
  }

zip_close($zip);
}
?>
```

Comment: zip_entry_read reads only 1024 bytes from file by default.. so contents is not full contents of the file, but only first 1024 bytes..

Comment: Warning: This function has been DEPRECATED

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this.

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

$zip->open(storage_path('app/'.$request->vrfile));

$name = '';

//looped through the zip files and got each index name of the files
//since I only wanted the first name which is the folder name I break the loop 
//after updating the variable $name with the index name and that's it

    for( $i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ ){
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        var_dump($filename);
        $name =     $filename;
        if ($i == 1){
            break;
        }
    }

    var_dump($name);
```

Comment: Why not use `$zip->getNameIndex(0);` without any loop and break etc.?

Comment: What's more, currently this will get the *second* entry...

Answer (score -8):

Repeated Question. Search before posting.
[PHP library that can list contents of zip / rar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524186/php-library-that-can-list-contents-of-zip-rar-files)

```
    <?php

 $rar_file = rar_open('example.rar') or die("Can't open Rar archive");

 $entries = rar_list($rar_file);

 foreach ($entries as $entry) {
     echo 'Filename: ' . $entry->getName() . "\n";
     echo 'Packed size: ' . $entry->getPackedSize() . "\n";
     echo 'Unpacked size: ' . $entry->getUnpackedSize() . "\n";

     $entry->extract('/dir/extract/to/');
 }

 rar_close($rar_file);

 ?>
```

Comment: lol so you scold for a duplicate question then subsidize the behavior with an answer. Nice :)

Comment: vote to close duplicate question instead of duplicating answers - you should read the Bible before preaching it.