# How to view any kind of document file in my view in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

If i want to view pdf, docx, doc, zip rar and others document in same view page. what should i do?

description:
If user upload a pdf file its need to show pdf and if user upload a doc file its need to show doc.
any solution please.

My view

```
@if($status->type == 1)
      <a href="{{ $status->image_url }}"></a>
         <img src="{{asset('status_images/'.$status->image_url)}}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;">

     @endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **iframes** to preview documents in your page. Simply provide the source of the document in the iframe src. You can use this method to preview pdf and document files. Now, Since browsers directly do not have integrated viewers for documents, you can use https://view.officeapps.live.com to preview Word, Excel, or PowerPoint document (as per the website). So, you can simply

```php
 @if(upload is image)
   <img src="{{image url}}"/>
 @elseif(upload is pdf)
   <iframe src="{{pdf url}}" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;min-height:640px;"></iframe>
 @elseif(upload is document)
   <iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src={{urlendoe(doc url)}}" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;min-height:640px;"></iframe>
 @else
   //manage things here
 @endif
```

If you want to preview zip and RAR files, check this out 
[In PHP is it possible to inspect the content of a Zip file without extracting its content first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817525/in-php-is-it-possible-to-inspect-content-of-a-zip-file-without-extracting-its-co)
. I personally have not used this, but, yeah this might help.

Comment: @Shuvo you dont need any configuration or services for it to work. Check if your urls are correct.

Comment: My path is status_docx i used itlike this but it still look like a white space.<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src={{asset('status_docx/'.$status->docx_url)}}" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;min-height:640px;"></iframe>  i am using local host. is it possible to view form local host???

Comment: How can i remove the download and other option forms it in view?

Comment: The function name is urlencode() not urlendoe()

Answer (score 0):

You can see PDF or image files with the integrated viewer that has the web browsers, but you can't do this with all formats. Some formats, like zip, rar,... must be downloaded to the desktop, tablet or mobile phone and viewed with the corresponding program.

Comment: How can i use integrated viewer??

Comment: The integrated viewer is integrated and it depends on your web browser (or your end user web browser), so you can't rely on an integrated viewer that can change from one web browser to another (v.gr. from Google Chrome to Mozilla Firefox or Microsoft Edge).

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src={{url("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.doc")}}" frameborder="0" style="width: 62%; min-height: 562px;"></iframe>
```

1. Offical office live helps to render files in iframe.
2. Above is the example to render dummy doc file.
3. Don't forget to use a live url for document instead of local
4. Copy paste & you are good to go.