# how to display image content of a Zip file without extracting its content first with php?

Tags: php

I tried this but not work

```
<?php
  $za = new ZipArchive();

  $za->open('zip1.zip');

  for ($i=0; $i < $za->numFiles ; $i++) { 
    $stat = $za->statIndex($i);
    print_r("<img src=" .basename($stat['name']) . PHP_EOL . "/>");
  }
?>
```

Comment: is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20206420/12232340

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the function [zip_entry_read()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-read.php)

An example how to use it you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_zip_entry_read.asp)